# Excel Convert Month Number to Month Name

Tags: excel-2013, date-conversion

Hi i tried to extract month name from date  in excel 2013

It looks like this:

```
2016-02-01
2016-02-02
2016-02-03
2016-02-03
2016-02-03
2016-02-04
```

In option - "Format Cells" i used "Custom" and used type - rrrr-mm-dd

Now i tried to get month name from those cells by using  methods:

```
TEXT(B4,"mmmm")
```

But i get error:
[image]

Comment: It can be because of the regional settings. Based on the language, it might not be "mmmm", or you may need to use `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: exactly this is it !!! Thanks :)